# How do I programmatically dismiss a crash dialog?

Tags: android, mdm

I'm building a DPC (Device Policy Controller), and one of the issues I'm seeing is that while the Play Store and Play Services are being updated, the Google Contact Sync service crashes -- leaving the typical crash dialog on the screen. Since part of the idea of the initial set up process is to have as little user interaction as possible, how can I dismiss this dialog programmatically (since I seem to be pretty much guaranteed that this will happen)?

I've tried dismissing system dialogs...

```
ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

... but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Since this is a DPC, anything that requires device ownership/administration is fine.

edit: Usually I have no UI on screen at the time, so if one is necessary please do mention it. Also, preferably the solution should work on at least 6.0+, if not 4.0+.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it onWindowsFocusChanged method  like this for example :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (!hasFocus) {
            Intent ctx= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(ctx);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure about app crash Dialog but maybe it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

AppErrorDialog can be dismissed by broadcasting ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS if Android version is N.

```
ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

However, AppErrorDialog won't be displayed if phone is locked.

```
public boolean canShowErrorDialogs() {
    return mShowDialogs && !mSleeping && !mShuttingDown
            && mLockScreenShown != LOCK_SCREEN_SHOWN;
} // ActivityManagerService
```

Comment: So close.. But sadly I need this to work on earlier versions, plus I need to keep the screen on so I can show my UI later (for some reason FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED aren't enough to break through the swipe keyguard on at least one test device).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
    try {

        Class ActivityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
        Class IActivityManager = Class.forName("android.app.IActivityManager");

        Method getDefault =  ActivityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault", null);
        Object am = IActivityManager.cast(getDefault.invoke(ActivityManagerNative, null));

        Method closeSystemDialogs =  am.getClass().getMethod("closeSystemDialogs", String.class);
        closeSystemDialogs.invoke(am, "DPC close");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this effectively the same as broadcasting the intent? Either way, it doesn't seem to have done anything and I don't get an exception.